# Add requirement to Symfony system

Tags: symfony, symfony3.x

In my Symfony project I'm using OpenSSL to encrypt/decrypt data. I can check if the cipher method that I want to use is avilable using `openssl_get_cipher_methods()`, but I dont want to perform this check everytime I run my code.

On the other hand Symfony has a way to check the system requirementes needed to run the project: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/requirements.html.

Is there a way I can add a new system requiremente to be checked? This way I could check for the available cipher just once and not everytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony requirements checker is part of [Symfony distribution bundle](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioDistributionBundle/blob/master/Resources/skeleton/app/SymfonyRequirements.php) and it is static.

However you can use [Composer scripts](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md) to perform required tasks upon install update or you can implement [Symfony cache warmer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html#kernel-cache-warmer) that will perform required tests during Symfony cache building process that is essential part of every Symfony application.